# Blizzard spell area of effect larger than range

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The blizzard spell in Frostburn has a larger area of effect than range. An 11th level druid casts at max range 840ft. area of effect is 1100ft. He is 160 ft. inside area of spell. How does this work?

Answer (score 14):

It’s broken. The authors forgot that spell areas cannot exceed their range:

> A spell’s range is the maximum distance from you that the spell’s effect can occur, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell’s point of origin. If any portion of the spell’s area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted.

<sup>([Magic Overview → Spell Descriptions → Range](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range))</sup>

Furthermore, note that, as a 5th-level spell, *blizzard*’s minimum caster level is 9th, at which point its range is 760 feet while its area is a 900-foot spread. That means at literally any level at which it is legal to cast *blizzard*, it cannot possibly use all of its area.

This also means it is impossible to cast *blizzard* without including yourself in the area: even if you put it all the way to the edge of the legal range, at the lowest legal caster level, the center of the area is 760 feet away while the effect reaches out 900 feet from that point—that is, 140 feet behind you. Like most spells, *blizzard* does not exempt the caster from its effect, so this means casting it guarantees you’ll be stuck in it.

Below caster level 40th, if you “center” its area at the edge of its range, its area covers a large portion of the range, but leave a crescent-shaped area unaffected on the side opposite where it was cast. At caster level 40th and above, *blizzard* will always simply fill the entire range unless there are obstructions, as its area will extend from one edge of its range to the other.

*Frostburn* is not a well-edited book, particularly its spells chapter; cf. *shivering touch* and *ice assassin*. There are certainly worse-edited books for D&D 3.5e, but *Frostburn* is definitely below average.

Comment: Please sir, where does it say that area cannot exceed range? Range is simply where you put the center or corner of the spell effect, the starting point basically. That should be independent from area, which is the region that the spell subsequently affects. Or so I thought, perhaps I missed it somewhere?

Comment: @nijineko [SRD link](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range); also in PHB and Rules Compendium (p. 126).  "A spell’s range is the maximum distance from you that the spell’s effect can occur, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell’s point of origin. If any portion of the spell’s area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted."

Comment: A small side note but applying [Enlarge Spell](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#enlargeSpell), either directly or with a [Metamagic Rod of Enlarge](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm#metamagicEnlarge) let's one use the full area of the spell at any caster level (up to CL 40).

Comment: @A_S00 Thank you very much, I appreciate the references and link. I did miss the last sentence you quoted.